# Word is default software for all extensions

Tags: windows, windows-7, updates

I have a huge problem on my windows 7.
All files are opening as Microsoft word as default. So if I want to open an pdf, it will open as encrypted on word. Even an audio file will open in word.

I tried to right click on the file change the default open with to Acrobat reader for PDFs, and now verything is opening as PDF even the audio files.

On my desktop, each file open with it's initial format, but when I click on start button everything has PDF icon and open with Acrobat.

Comment: Try to create new account and check if on it the situation will be the same. If yes, it will be the problem with global file association, but if not, maybe you can move your data from old to this new created profile and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Control Panel** and select **Large icons** from the **View by:** drop down.  Click on **Default Programs** and select **Set your default programs**.  Select **Word** and **PDF** from the **Programs** list and choose **Set this program as default**.

That should only set the defaults for only the file types it recognizes, instead of everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed any other Doc Viewer, Right-Click > Open With.. Select Make Default icon (if you want it as permanent).